# Prononciation de "Yaourt"

Tags: vocabulaire, prononciation, alimentation

Prononce-t-on le '**t**' de '**yaourt**' en français ? Je trouve souvent des sources contradictoires sur Internet, par exemple :

- https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/yaourt-yogourt-yoghourt-yaourth-sic.273328/?hl=fr : Beaucoup affirment que le 't' ne se prononce pas
- https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/yaourt : Wiktionary précise que le 't' se prononce

Comment: Dit-on "pain au chocolat" ou "chocolatine" ? :p

Comment: @Nathan Et pour "ananas" ? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ça dépend de la région de laquelle on est originaire ! En France, on dit *yaourT* de partout sauf en Bretagne (*yaour*) et en Savoie (yogourT, comme en Suisse et en Belgique). Cartographie et explications sur ce site : https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/08/19/ces-mots-quon-ne-sait-jamais-comment-prononcer/

Answer (score 3):

La source wordreference dit qu'au Canada les gens utilisent plutôt 'yogourt', sans prononcer le [t], prononçant ainsi 'yogour'.
Par contre, cette source précise aussi qu'on dit 'yaourt' avec un [t]. À la fin seulement, quelqu'un précise qu'on dit parfois 'yaour' (comme moi par exemple). Mais c'est juste une façon de prononcer 'non officielle'.

Answer (score 3):

*Le Petit Robert 1984* indique **yaourt** [jauʁ, jauʁt], ce qui selon le principe de transcription retenu (présenté au début du dictionnaire) indique que les deux prononciations sont considérées également correctes, et que la prononciation *yaour* est la plus fréquente. À l'article même, avant la définition, on mentionne la variante **yog(h)ourt** [jɔɡuʁ(t)], ce qui de nouveau indique deux prononciations considérée également correctes, celle sans *T* de nouveau la plus fréquente.

En 2010, on a changé son fusil d'épaule : nous avons désormais **yaourt** [ˈjauʁt]¹, et à la toute fin de l'article la variante **yogourt** [ˈjɔɡuʁt]. Selon le choix de la présentation phonétique de cette édition, on peut conclure qu'il s'agit là des prononciations les plus conformes à celles observées récemment par des locuteurs urbains éduqués d'Île-de-France et de régions voisines. Il est clairement indiqué que ce choix n'est pas destiné à *« choquer les utilisateurs d'usages plus anciens, ruraux ou de régions où subsiste soit un bilinguisme, soit l'influence d'une autre langue ou de dialectes »*. Nous avons donc ici des propositions, non des normes.

Quant au *Petit Larousse*, les éditions 1992 et 2003 présentent la même information, soit **yaourt** [jauʁt], **yogourt** ou **yoghourt** [joɡuʁt]. Les prononciations dans le *Petit Larousse* ne sont pas systématiques, mais limitées aux *« mots français qui présentent une difficulté »*, sans autre spécification.

---

En France métropolitaine, le *T* se prononcerait pour les deux mots, selon les informations de @George M en commentaire ci-dessous, quoique la prononciation sans *T* semble avoir été elle aussi bien courante il y a une quarantaine d'années, si l'on se fie à l'information du *Petit Robert 1984*. Elle est possiblement en recul aujourd'hui.

Au Québec (d'où je viens), peu de gens utilisent *yaourt*, mais il est généralement admis que le *T* se prononce, alors que *yogourt* est pratiquement universel, mais à peu près toujours prononcé sans *T*.

---

- ¹ Le symbole ˈ n'indique pas ici la syllabe tonique (selon la norme habituelle de l'API), mais l'absence de liaison ou d'élision, selon les habitudes du *Petit Robert.* L'absence de ce symbole dans la version 1984 n'indique pas qu'elle n'était pas la norme, on s'en convaincra facilement grâce à l'exemple de Marcel Aymé, présent dans les deux versions :

  > *Il rangeait des pots **de** yaourth* [sic], *sorte de lait caillé d'une assez grande réputation, quoique sans orthographe bien sûre.*

Comment: En France metropolitaine, le 't' se prononce toujours, dans les 2 cas.